# What does the word "individual" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from a software's description:

> You can create individual greeting cards or order celebration cards in
>   bulk.

Does the word "individual" mean here "separate"? Or does it mean "customizable"?

The software gives the user options to create calendars, cards, books, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can create individual greeting cards or order celebration cards in bulk.

They are contrasting the words "individual" and "bulk". The opposite of bulk.

Individual can mean "a single thing, being, instance, or item."  Not many, just a single one.

In the context of "you can *create*", the sentence implies *customizable*.

An "individual" means a distinct, separate, single entity that may (or may not) be different from all others.